# Position a div on the same display-position at any resolution?

Tags: html, css

For example I have a 10" display.
This display has either a resolution of 640x480 or 800x600.

How can I position a div always at the same display-position (for example 5cm from the top) regardless of which resolution is enabled?

This doesn't work, does it?

```
top: 5cm
```

Comment: "5cm" only works for print style sheets. The browser doesn't know the DPI of your display and won't know how many pixels are represented by 5cm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use percentages.

```
top: 10%;
```

will position the div at the same place on any display regardless of resolution as long as the physical dimensions of the displays are the same.